# python3 how to install automatically module?

Tags: python

I try to install required module like this:

```
try:
    import pyAesCrypt

    print('package: pyAesCrypt found')
except:
    mod_inst = subprocess.Popen("pip3  install pyAesCrypt", shell=True) 
    mod_inst.wait()

    import pyAesCrypt
    print('package: ' + package + ' installed')
```

As a result I get the following errors, how to make my code work?

```
Collecting pyAesCrypt
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/99/ebae89da08a443d0191eff631d66b71955eec7e370e2a309d85e499ca18a/pyAesCrypt-0.4.3-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pyAesCrypt) (2.6.1)
Installing collected packages: pyAesCrypt
Successfully installed pyAesCrypt-0.4.3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "smb.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pyAesCrypt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyAesCrypt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "smb.py", line 13, in <module>
    import pyAesCrypt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyAesCrypt'
```

Comment: how to make my code work?

Comment: `mod_inst = subprocess.Popen("python -m pip  install pyAesCrypt", shell=True)`

Comment: the same result..

Comment: considering you call by `python3` interminal and `pip3` is used/install in python then use `mod_inst = subprocess.Popen("python3 -m pip3 install pyAesCrypt", shell=True)`

Comment: Does this code work for you?

Comment: yes, you need to check if you are using a virtual environment or not also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have multiple python versions?

Comment: you have to ensure the pip installing the module is the same one running your program